# ASP.Net Core AzureAD authentication works but the SignIn and SignOut don't

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure, asp.net-core

I hope that I've got the right corner for my question.
If not i will delete it and post it in the right place.

Well after fighting for hours I’m asking you guys….

I’m playing a little bit around with asp.net core and the AzureAD authentication with a microsoft account.
I’ve created a demo project with VS2019 and followed everything in this example:
(I didn't change anything on the project except installing Microsoft.Identity.Web and Microsoft.Identity.Web.UI via NuGet; and making those changes in the tutorial).

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-web-app-sign-user-app-configuration?tabs=aspnetcore

I’ve registered the app on the azure portal
When im running the app everything is working.
I’ve been redirected to microsoft; typed in my credentials and i was logged in.
worked like a charm.

The only thing that i’m facing:
the SignIn and SignOut buttons aren’t working.

When i run the app and looked at the raw html source i’ve noticed that

```
<a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="MicrosoftIdentity" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="SignOut">Sign Out</a>
```

resulted in:

```
<li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link text-dark" href="">Sign out</a>
</li>
```

When i run the project and type: https://localhost:44311/signout-oidc i’m directed to a blank page.
When i hit the return button of the browser I've noticed that im logged-out.
So i think it's generally working but the MicrosoftIdentity isn’t creating the links as expected.

Maybe I’m missing some hint…
Any ideas? Thanks in Advance!

appsettings.json

```
{
  "AzureAd": {
    // Azure cloud instance among:
    // - "https://login.microsoftonline.com/" for Azure public cloud
    // - "https://login.microsoftonline.us/" for Azure US government
    // - "https://login.microsoftonline.de/" for Azure AD Germany
    // - "https://login.chinacloudapi.cn/" for Azure AD China operated by 21Vianet
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",

    // Azure AD audience among:
    // - "TenantId" as a GUID obtained from the Azure portal to sign in users in your organization
    // - "organizations" to sign in users in any work or school account
    // - "common" to sign in users with any work or school account or Microsoft personal account
    // - "consumers" to sign in users with a Microsoft personal account only
    "TenantId": "*******************************",

    // Client ID (application ID) obtained from the Azure portal
    "ClientId": "*******************************",
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc",
    "SignedOutCallbackPath": "/signout-oidc"
  },

  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

Startup.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Authorization;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Identity;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web.UI;

namespace WebApplication2
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddRazorPages();

            services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebAppAuthentication(Configuration, "AzureAd");

            services.AddRazorPages().AddMvcOptions(options =>
            {
                var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                              .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                              .Build();
                options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
            }).AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

_Layout.cshtml

```
@using Microsoft.Identity;
@using Microsoft.Identity.Web;
@using Microsoft.Identity.Web.UI;
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Authorization;
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>@ViewData["Title"] - WebApplication2</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-light bg-white border-bottom box-shadow mb-3">
            <div class="container">
                <a class="navbar-brand" asp-area="" asp-page="/Index">WebApplication2</a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
                        aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse d-sm-inline-flex flex-sm-row-reverse">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav flex-grow-1">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-page="/Index">Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-page="/Privacy">Privacy</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                <partial name="_LoginPartial" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <div class="container">
        <main role="main" class="pb-3">
            @RenderBody()
        </main>
    </div>

    <footer class="border-top footer text-muted">
        <div class="container">
            &copy; 2021 - WebApplication2 - <a asp-area="" asp-page="/Privacy">Privacy</a>
        </div>
    </footer>

    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>

    @RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

_LoginPartial.cshtml

```
<ul class="navbar-nav">
    @if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        <li class="nav-item">
            <span class="navbar-text text-dark">Hello!</span>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="MicrosoftIdentity" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="SignOut">Sign out</a>
        </li>
    }
    else
    {
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="MicrosoftIdentity" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="SignIn">Sign in</a>
        </li>
    }
</ul>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to enable MVC endpoint route.

ConfigureService:

```
services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
{
    var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
        .Build();
    options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
}).AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();
```

Configure:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default",
        pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    endpoints.MapRazorPages();
});
```

Comment: That's it! Thank you buddy!

Comment: So wait .. they support razor pages and MVC, but when you want to sign out you need to enable controllers/views anyway?  haha okay ..:(

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue for a new Razor Pages project (.NET5).

Fixed after I add `endpoints.MapControllers()` to `app.UseEndpoints` in **Startup.cs**.

In `Configure`:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllers(); // line to add
    endpoints.MapRazorPages();
});
```

In `ConfigureService`:

```
services.AddRazorPages().AddMvcOptions(options => {
    var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                    .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                    .Build();

    options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
}).AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using ASP.NET Core Identity with *external* Azure AD login

- Setup/Double-check the correct version
  Ensure you setup your `CookieSchemeName` to `Identity.External` in services, this tells asp.net core identity to get the external user profile from external identity provider like Azure AD

  ```
  services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
       options.UseSqlServer(
           Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
   services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>()
       .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

   services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddAzureAD(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options));

   services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(AzureADDefaults.OpenIdScheme, options =>
   {
       //double check your version here
       options.Authority = options.Authority + "/v2.0/";
       options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidateIssuer = false;

   });
  ```
- Azure AD application setting :

  ```
   "AzureAd": {
       "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
       "Domain": "xxx.onmicrosoft.com",
       "TenantId": "xxxxxx-xxxxx-yyy-b544-TYKT.org.asset",
       "ClientId": "xxxxx-xxxxx-TYKT-xxx-vvyy",
       "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc",
       "CookieSchemeName": "Identity.External"
   },
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a controller like [this](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-identity-web/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Identity.Web.UI/Areas/MicrosoftIdentity/Controllers/AccountController.cs)? - Following [this part of the tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-web-app-sign-user-sign-in?tabs=aspnetcore).

It is the address `account/signout` that is supposed to handle the sign out for you.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I don't have a controller because I've installed Microsoft.Identity.Web and Microsoft.Identity.Web.UI via NuGet. As described in the tutorial you don't need a controller  because the controller is provided by the Microsoft.Identity.Web.UI

Comment: Ok, sorry I hadn't understood that. So, please make sure that you can access that `account/signout` endpoint. It is normal that the `signout-oidc` leads to a blank page, since it is not meant to be used that way. Other thing that you may do, given that either sign-in nor sign-out buttons are working, is debug your cshtml code.